# PhPmyadmin SQL Query to insert meta_key & value IF another value exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, insert-select

Ok I am looking for an sql query to insert meta_key & value in a specific table IF another value exist. I am using wordpress database.

I want a query to search the "**wp_postmeta**" table for "**qty (meta_key)**" with "**0 (meta_value)**" and insert to all those posts a new meta_key "**_wplp_post_front**" with meta_value "**1**"

I am new with phpmyadmin and I really need help.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_____UPDATE!!!**
Ok once again i have found the solution from third party website:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value, post_id)
SELECT "_wplp_post_front", 1, post_id
 FROM wp_postmeta outside_table
 WHERE meta_key = 'qty'
 AND meta_value = '0'
 AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id = outside_table.post_id
AND meta_key = "_wplp_post_front"
AND meta_value = 1
)
```

Comment: Do you want to write it in php? or just to test in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Looking to find a way to succeed this either with php code or with phpmyadmin

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! You should post your solution as an answer, then accept it, so this question doesn't show as unresolved.

Comment: Thank you Isaac, from now on, I will publish the solutions in this way. Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok once again i have found the solution from third party website:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value, post_id)
SELECT "_wplp_post_front", 1, post_id
 FROM wp_postmeta outside_table
 WHERE meta_key = 'qty'
 AND meta_value = '0'
 AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id = outside_table.post_id
AND meta_key = "_wplp_post_front"
AND meta_value = 1
)
```